# How do I upgrade to Python 3.6 with Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to get the latest version of Python to use [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) in my code. Currently my version is (`python -V`):

```
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)
```

How would I upgrade to Python 3.6?

Comment: The second answer is, I think, the better answer, especially for those who have a "master"/"default" environment in which the latest and greatest is continually updated.

Comment: delete original env, create new env with the right python version with original name and re-run your installation script e.g. `install.sh`

Comment: Is it necessary for it to be tagged with macOS?

Answer (score 420, accepted):

Anaconda had not updated Python internally to 3.6, but later versions of Anaconda has a Python 3.6 version [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

a) Method 1

1. If you wanted to update, you will type `conda update python`
2. To update Anaconda, type `conda update conda`
3. If you want to upgrade between major python versions, like 3.5 to 3.6, you'll have to do

   ```
   conda install python=$pythonversion$
   ```

b) Method 2 - Create a new environment (the better method)

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

c) To get the absolute latest Python (3.6.5 at time of writing)

```
conda create --name py365 python=3.6.5 --channel conda-forge
```

You can see all this from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#package-update).

Also, refer to this for force [upgrading](https://www.scivision.dev/switch-anaconda-latest-python-3/).

Comment: Unless Continuum have changed how conda operates, you cannot upgrade major Python versions by `conda update python`. See here: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#update-or-upgrade-python

Comment: conda install python=$pythonversion$  e.g. conda install python=3.6

Comment: `conda update python` just took me from 3.6.5 to 3.7.0. Neat!

Comment: FYI method a) works for changing between different versions of python as well, as long as it doesn't break any dependencies within the venv

Comment: @fredrik `conda update python` bricked my conda installation.

Comment: your solution makes me have to install all my old packages again from scratch. You should mention how to get around that. The title says upgrade so that is a sensible expectation for a good answer.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade python within an environment that has an older python version without having to create a new environment? Searched everywhere, seems it's not possible.

Comment: @Adel Did you try `conda install python=...`?

Answer (score 40):

Creating a new environment will install Python 3.6:

```
conda create --name 3point6 python=3.6
```

Output:

```
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/dstansby/miniconda3/envs/3point6:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    openssl:    1.0.2j-0
    pip:        9.0.1-py36_1
    python:     3.6.0-0
    readline:   6.2-2
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py36_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0
    tk:         8.5.18-0
    wheel:      0.29.0-py36_0
    xz:         5.2.2-1
    zlib:       1.2.8-3
```

Comment: If your conda installation is for Python 2.7 then conda create will create a 2.7 version. changing command to `conda create --name 3point6 python=3` (adding `=3` at the end) makes a python3 version.

Comment: It will indeed. I've changed my answer to specify python 3.6!

Comment: your solution makes me have to install all my old packages again from scratch. You should mention how to get around that. The title says upgrade so that is a sensible expectation for a good answer.

Answer (score 33):

I found [this page](https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2797011-updating-anaconda-to-python-3-6) with detailed instructions to upgrade Anaconda to a major newer version of Python (from Anaconda 4.0+).  First,

```
conda update conda
conda remove argcomplete conda-manager
```

I also had to `conda remove` some packages not on the official list:

- backports_abc
- beautiful-soup
- blaze-core

Depending on packages installed on your system, you may get additional `UnsatisfiableError` errors. Simply add those packages to the remove list. Next, install the version of Python,

```
conda install python==3.6
```

which takes a while, after which a message indicated to `conda install anaconda-client`, so I did

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

which says it's already there.  Finally, following the directions,

```
conda update anaconda
```

I did this in the Windows 10 command prompt, but things should be similar in Mac OS X.

Comment: page link now broken.

Answer (score 22):

In the past, I have found it quite difficult to try to upgrade in-place.

Note: my use-case for Anaconda is as an all-in-one Python environment. I don't bother with separate virtual environments. If you're using `conda` to create environments, this may be destructive because `conda` creates environments with hard-links inside your `Anaconda/envs` directory.

So if you use environments, you may first want to [export your environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-file). After activating your environment, do something like:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

After backing up your environments (if necessary), you may remove your old Anaconda (it's very simple to uninstall Anaconda):

```
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3/
```

and replace it by downloading the new Anaconda, e.g. Linux, 64 bit:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

([see here for a more recent one](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/)),

and then executing it:

```
$ bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to upgrade the Python version inside your existing environment, activate it first with `conda activate <env_name>` and then do:

```
conda install -c anaconda python=<version>
```

You might also need to update the dependencies with

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: This worked fine for me (upgraded from 3.6 -> 3.9 within an environment with many packages in it).  Not sure what all the other complicated answers are for. Thanks.

Comment: Why `-c anaconda`? Isn't that the default?

Answer (score 17):

I'm using [macOS v10.14 (Mojave)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave).

These four steps worked for me.

1. `conda update conda`
2. `conda install python=3.6`
3. `conda install anaconda-client`
4. `conda update anaconda`

Comment: It works.  It will use "flexible solve" when solving the environment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that works was creating a new Conda environment with the name you want (you will, unfortunately, delete the old one to keep the name). Then create a new environment with a new Python version and rerun your `install.sh` script with the Conda/pip installs (or the YAML file or whatever you use to keep your requirements):

```
conda remove --name original_name --all
conda create --name original_name python=3.8
sh install.sh  # Or whatever you usually do to install dependencies
```

Doing `conda install python=3.8` doesn't work for me. Also, why do you want 3.6? Move forward with the world ;)

---

## Note the below doesn't work:

If you want to update the Conda version of your previous environment you can also do the following (more complicated than it should be because [you cannot rename environments in Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231764/how-can-i-rename-a-conda-environment)):

1. create a temporary new location for your current environment:

   ```
   conda create --name temporary_env_name --clone original_env_name
   ```
2. delete the original env (so that the new env can have that name):

   ```
   conda deactivate
   conda remove --name original_env_name --all # Or its alias: `conda env remove --name original_env_name`
   ```
3. then create the new empty environment with the Python version you want and clone the original environment:

   ```
   conda create --name original_env_name python=3.8 --clone temporary_env_name
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I manage to get (as currently there isn't any direct support. In the future, it will be for sure) Python 3.9 in earlier versions of Anaconda and Windows 10.

**Note:** I needed extra packages, so install them. Install only what you need

```
conda create --name e39 python=3.9 --channel conda-forge
```

Python 3.9 is available with later versions of conda. Use the below command:

```
conda create --name <myenv> python=3.9
```

And it will create your Python 3.9 virtual environment simply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open an Anaconda PowerShell prompt as an **administrator user.**
2. Type in `conda update python`.
3. Wait about 10 minutes. In this process, you may need to type in `y` at some time.
4. After completing, check your Python version in Conda by typing `python  --version`
5. If it is the newest version, then you can restart your computer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to preserve the specific versions of the packages currently in your environment, this is the best method I found (at the time of the answer):

```
source activate old_env
conda env export > old_env.yml
```

Then process it with something like this:

```
with open('old_env.yml', 'r') as fin, open('new_env.yml', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if 'py35' in line:  # replace by the version you want to supersede
            line = line[:line.rfind('=')] + '\n'
        fout.write(line)
```

Then edit manually the first (`name: ...`) and last line (`prefix: ...`) to reflect your new environment name and run:

```
conda env create -f new_env.yml
```

You might need to remove or change manually the version pin of a few packages for which which the pinned version from `old_env` is found incompatible or missing for the new python version.

I wish there was a built-in, easier way...

If you don't mind possibly some changes of the version of the other packages of your environment, the other answers provides various ways to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You can first remove the existing Python if any and then install the required version, sometimes directly installing the required version without removing the existing version causes compatibility issues.

```
conda activate your_env
conda uninstall python
conda install python=3.6
```