# Conda install python3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, conda

I'm getting this error on Ubuntu 14.04, trying to re-install python3.6 which was very recently located in my directory here:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python3.6
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
$ conda install python=3.6
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python=3.6
  - ssl_match_hostname -> python=2.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How would I debug this?  The output of

```
conda info ssl_match_hostname
```

doesn't seem very informative.

Comment: Can you give the output of `~/anaconda3/bin/python --version`? I'm guessing that your root conda python i.e. `~/anaconda3/bin/python` is python 2.7 instead of 3.6.

Comment: Also, what is it that you're exactly trying to do? If you want to upgrade the python version then I recommend following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda) instead. If you're trying to do a complete re-installation then I would suggest re-installing Anaconda itself using their shell script.

Comment: ```$  ~/anaconda3/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)```

Comment: Oddly, my ```activate``` seems to have broken, too. 
conda activate

```CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had mentioned in the comment that the output of `~/anaconda3/bin/python --version` gives you `Python 2.7.13`.

This means that you cannot do `conda install python=3.6` since every package in your root environment is built for python 2.7. So I would suggest you to re-download the Anaconda3 package from the website to get the latest version of both Python & Anaconda. It may even resolve your `conda activate` issues.

**Edit**

You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda) for a little more explanation.