# Anaconda Does not Have Latest Python (3.6.4)? [I have tried what is on Google!!]

Tags: python, anaconda

*It really cannot work although I try all the possible methods in the answers and the google!*

In our university, we are required to use python 3.6.4 (latest version possible). However, when using anaconda to install it (see the command below), I can only get 3.6.2. Because 3.6.2 was released long ago at 2017.07.17, I am quite confused why there is no newer version.

[UPDATE] about: I try to install 3.6.4 but failed.
[UPDATE] about: Use deafult channels but get 3.6.3

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me **install the newest python in anaconda**. Thank you very much!

Details:

Inputed

```
conda create -n csc python=3.6
```

and only installed the python with version

```
(csc) C:\Users\[MYUSERNAME]>python --version
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

---

Updated:

```
(csc) C:\Users\[NAME]>conda install python=3.6.4
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\[NAME]>conda create -n csc python=3.6.4
```

Both result in:

```
Fetching package metadata .................

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - python 3.6.4*

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

I even tried:

```
(csc) C:\Users\fzyzcjy>conda update python
```

But only result in:

```
Fetching package metadata .................
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\csc:
#
python                    3.6.2                         0    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free
```

UPDATE2: try to use default channel - only 3.6.3!

```
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\fzyzcjy>conda create -n csc1002 python=3.6 --channel anaconda
Fetching package metadata ...................
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3\envs\csc1002:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2017.11.5-py36hb8ac631_0 anaconda
    pip:            9.0.1-py36h226ae91_4     anaconda
    python:         3.6.3-h3b118a2_4         anaconda
    setuptools:     36.5.0-py36h65f9e6e_0    anaconda
    vc:             14-h2379b0c_2            anaconda
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0             anaconda
    wheel:          0.30.0-py36h6c3ec14_1    anaconda
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0       anaconda
```

UPDATE3: Using @James' suggested channel it finally works!

```
(csc) C:\Users\[NAME]>conda install python=3.6.4 --channel conda-forge
Fetching package metadata ...................
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3\envs\csc:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    python: 3.6.2-0 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free --> 3.6.4-0 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

python-3.6.4-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:19 964.70 kB/s

(csc) C:\Users\fzyzcjy>python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda

Comment: @dkato sorry but it still gives me 3.6.2

Comment: Consider that for your purpose at university the difference in versions will be negligible. Therefore go on and install 3.6.2, scipy, numpy, matplotlib and alike will work the same

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera sorry but the professor does not allow 3.6.2 although I do not know why...

Comment: I wonder why downvotes... I have tried every method on google.

Comment: @Turtle take a look to my update, and let me know.

Comment: @GiulioBambini ok wait a second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base environment that Anaconda installs uses 3.6.4 in the latest release.  However, you can easily create a new environment using Conda to get the latest version.  At the command line run:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6.4 --channel conda-forge
```

This will create a new environment.  To activate the environment, run:

```
(on Windows)> activate myenv
(on Linux  )$ source activate myenv
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work, which can be seen in the updated question

Comment: You have a custom channel set.  Updating.

Comment: It looks like conda-forge has the latest.  Updating again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not obliged to create a separate Anaconda environment and your purpose is to change the global version of Anaconda Python, try:

```
conda install python=3.6.4
```

If the package is missing you could try locally with:

```
conda install --use-local your_file_version.tar.bz2
```

See the screen below:
[image: versions]

You can download the packages [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.6.4)

**Update:** For windows users you need to download the packages from [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files?version=3.6.4) using `conda-forge`

[image: conda-forge]

Comment: Sorry but it does not work, which can be seen in the updated question

Comment: Is that available for *windows* users?

Comment: It seems that it does not have windows version available

Comment: You welcome @Turtle.. actually I didn't realized that you striclty needed the win version. Although you have already choose the best answer, I have updated the url with conda-forge python versions (also compatible with windows).

Comment: Thank you as well, and I have given you an upvote too :)