# Problems installing Python3.6 using Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Linux and trying to install `Python 3.6` using `Anaconda`, given the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda/41550734).

When I run `conda install python==3.6`, I get the following:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - jupyter_contrib_nbextensions -> jupyter_nbextensions_configurator[version='>=0.2.8'] -> python=3.5
  - python==3.6
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How do I fix this error? I already have Python 3.5 and I'd like to upgrade to 3.6 .

Comment: why not use a new environment for py36 ?

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to another question (if you are trying to update an already installed version of anaconda)

One option is to update anaconda using

```
conda update --all
```

For more on this look to: [How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)

Also, if you are entering

```
conda install python==$pythonversion$
```

It should be

```
conda install python==3.6
```

If you are going to Python 3.6 (just checking)