# Removed Python 2.7.15 and installed 3.7.1, but Spyder remains python 2.7.15

Tags: python, spyder

Opening an interactive in Spyder shows the following:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09)[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.7.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

As you can see, it still shows Python 2.7.15. How do I change the Python version that Spyder uses?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd need more information in order to give you directions. 
Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux?

Why is it important? Because Mac and Linux already have a native python 2, that might be conflicting.

Again, since we're talking about Anaconda, it works as a Virtual Environment, and thus can contain specific libs and other components not available on your computer, so you should install python 3 directly there.

Try this: [How do I upgrade to Python 3.6 with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda)

Comment: ,windows,TypeError: unhashable type

Answer (score 0):

In the Anaconda prompt upgrade your python version

```
conda update python
```