# How to downgrade Python from 3.7 to 3.5 in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I've been trying to downgrade the version of Python in Anaconda as it doesn't support TensorFlow and I get the following error(s):

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvHPA.jpg)

Comment: til tensorflow doesn't support python 3.7 yet... the world is ending.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code/exceptions as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post. Posting exceptions as Images follows the same logic as posting code. Simply [edit] your question and post the error/exception/code as _text_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to Python 3.6 with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda)

Comment: Downgrade the *global* version, or simply create an environment with an older version?

Comment: just remove the version you have (seems you have something corrupted) and install one for your need ... http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-get-the-latest-anaconda-with-python-3-5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a new environment for your experiments:

```
conda create -n new_environment python=3.5
```

Or install anaconda with another python version (http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-get-the-latest-anaconda-with-python-3-5)

Answer (score 5):

From your error output it is clear there is a **dependency conflict**:
backports.os requires python 2.7.

Simply uninstall backports.os like this:
`conda uninstall backports.os`
And then downgrade Python:
`conda install python=3.5`

The fact that you're on Python 3.7, but backports.os is still requiring Python 2.7 is proof something has gone wrong with your setup. If you still require backports.os, simply reinstall it when Python is downgraded: `conda install backports.os`.