# How can I download Anaconda for python 3.6

Tags: python, anaconda

I was working on Tensorflow object detection project, for this I am using Anaconda 3 with python 3.7 but I am facing some issues while running object detection demo, I read couple of posts here on stackoverflow and found that it can be solved by using Anaconda with python 3.6 but this version is not available at Anaconda's [download](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) page, there are only two versions i.e for Python 3.7 and Python 2.7 but I need for Python 3.6.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6), with an installation of the last anaconda you can create an environment just [like Cleb explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801571/1534017) or downgrade python :

```
conda install python=3.6.0
```

With this second solution, you may encounter some incompatibility issues with other packages. I tested it myself and did not encounter any issue but I guess it depends on the packages you installed.

If you don't want to handle environments or face incompatibilities issues, you can download any Anaconda version here: https://repo.continuum.io/archive/. For example, Anaconda3-5.1.0-XXX or Anaconda3-5.2.0-XXX provides python 3.6 (the suffix XXX depends on your OS).

To know which python is provided in an anaconda package, you can visit the [Release notes page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/). It provides the updates for the all anaconda versions. Find yours and look for the line

> python A.B.C -> X.Y.Z

where A.B.C is the previous version and X.Y.Z is the updated python version.

Comment: Thanks man, I downloaded, Anaconda3-5.2.0-XXX and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome, I wonder why there is no link to old versions in the download page

Comment: Hi How to find python version in the  https://repo.continuum.io/archive/. I am looking for python 3.6.9, same tensorflow issue with 3.7

Comment: I don't know which one exactly, you can try 5.3.0 or  5.3.1

Comment: it not working PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current ch
nnels:

Comment: I guess you tried to downgrade python. What does `conda search python` returns?

Comment: @hanzgs Anaconda3-5.2.0-XXX is the last version with Python 3.6. It has Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 25):

[This link](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) has history version about Anaconda, you could download from this website.

At version 5.3.0 python 3.6 support was dropped...

> ### Anaconda 5.3.0 (Sept 28, 2018)
>
> #### User-facing changes
>
> The Anaconda3 installers ship with python 3.7 instead of python 3.6
>
> python 3.6.5 -> 3.7.0

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/#anaconda-5-3-0-sept-28-2018

The last version released with a python3.6 variant was version 5.2.0

> ### Anaconda 5.2.0 (May 30, 2018)
>
> python 3.6.4 -> 3.6.5

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/#anaconda-5-2-0-may-30-2018

The links to this latest version are...

- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-ppc64le.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-ppc64le.sh)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86.sh)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86.exe](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86.exe)
- [Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Comment: Where does it say which python a version comes with? I would have expected this information to be provided in some description field for a package but don't see em to be able to find one. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can download the 3.7 version and then [use](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

```
conda create -n mygreatenvironment python=3.6 <add other packages here>
```

and then:

```
conda activate mygreatenvironment
```

This environment will use Python 3.6.

Comment: Don't forget to remove 'source' on a windows machine :)

Comment: @cb14: Good point :) I replaced it by `conda` which - I think - works on any operating system.

Comment: Your solution is the best one among all!

Answer (score 6):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda), this solution is working for me on windows 10,

From the anaconda prompt :

1. Create a custom environnement and specify the repository channel to find the version (in my case 3.6.5)

```
    conda create --name py365 python=3.6.5 --channel conda-forge
```

2. Activate the new environment

```
    conda activate py365
```

But the activation won't be permanent, you will need to activate each time you start the anaconda prompt

3. Create a shortcut to Anaconda prompt with your choosen environment

In order to activate permanently your custom environment, you can create a anaconda prompt shortcut which new target.
Go to

```
C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)
```

And Copy and rename the file `Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)` to `Anaconda 3.6.5`.
Then right-click on the new file and click on "Properties".

Then change the target :

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Your_Name\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Your_Name\Anaconda3
```

to

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Your_Name\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Your_Name\Anaconda3\envs\py365
```

(be aware to change "Your_Name" by your "real" name )

Finally, if you go to your Windows Start menu, you will see your new shortcut "Anaconda 3.6.5" which launch the Anaconda Prompt with your choosen environment !

Answer (score 0):

You can download anaconda from the archives.

The path I followed was:
Anaconda Documentation>Anaconda Distribution>Installation-(in page)System Requirements>[archive](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/)

I was looking for installation instructions on my CentOS machine when I stumbled upon the question.

Answer (score 0):

For installing python 3.6 on windows go to this [link](https://anaconda.org/ehmoussi/python)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).