# How to find python version in anaconda continuum repo?

Tags: python, anaconda

TensorFlow is not working in python 3.7, I wish to install anaconda with python 3.6.9, in the https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ I couldn't find which version, also the https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section having only for python 3.7.

How to find Anaconda2-5.3.1-Windows-x86.exe (in the archive) having which version of python. Looking for Windows

I am not looking to create conda env for python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

By default, the detailed version is [not supported.](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/oldpkglists/)

If you want Python in version 3.6.9 (with Anaconda)

I recommend to install [version 3.6.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801513/how-can-i-download-anaconda-for-python-3-6) (I know you don't want...)

This seems to be a policy implemented by the Anaconda side for version-specific management.

Answer (score 0):

By default Anaconda comes with Python 3.7.3, I installed that. Spyder opens with 3.7, Then in Anaconda Prompt, conda version is 4.7.10, with this Python downgrade it is not supported properly:

```sh
conda update conda
```

gives 4.7.11, then

```sh
conda install python=3.6.9
```

installs Python 3.6.9 smoothly, Spyder opens with 3.6,

Now TensorFlow works like a charm

Comment: Just an info, Python 3.7.3 got updated patch for tensorflow, tf works smooth in py3.7.3 with keras 2.2.5 and tensorflow 1.14.0