# Using python 3.6 in new Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I am creating a new anaconda environment(my first) in Anaconda Navigator. The libraries I intend to use require python 3.6 but from the python packages drop-down list(see screenshot below) I'm only seeing python 3.8. How can I install python 3.6 to anaconda so that it appears in the drop-down list?

[image]

Comment: This link will be useful to solve the above issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801513/how-can-i-download-anaconda-for-python-3-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an environment from the start

```
conda create --name my_env python=3.6.5
```

To install pyhton in an existing environment

```
conda install python=3.6.5
```