# Can't change the version of python in my conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, version

I am trying to change the version of python running my conda environment.

I activate the environment by executing:

```
conda activate medcat
```

and I attempt to change the python version by executing:

```
conda install python=3.6.1
```

This leads to conda attempting to install the python=3.6.1 as if it were a package and I get the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.6.1
```

Am I missing something? This doesn't seem like the standard behaviour for anaconda. Furthermore if I try to create a completely new environment by executing:

```
conda create --name medcat2 python=3.6.1
```

I get the exact same error.

Comment: Have you installed Python without the standard version which comes with the Anaconda Distribution? It might be the case that since there is only one version of python installed(the one shipped with Anaconda) no other version can be found...
I hope this thread could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972722/why-cant-i-change-the-python-version-of-my-conda-environment

Answer (score 3):

Typing `conda search python` should give you a list of available python versions. For me Version 3.6.1 isn't in there. However version 3.6.2 is and I also could install it with `conda install python=3.6.2`

Comment: Thanks for this. I resolved this shortly after I posted by just installing python=3.6. Seems weird to me that 3.6.1 doesn't exist though.

Comment: Just speculation, but I guess that 3.6.2 is basically the same as 3.6.1 but with some bug-fixes. Therefore 3.6.1 isn't needed.