# How to tell conda which verison of python to install a package to

Tags: python, package, conda

My base conda environment is set up like this

```
python (or python2)
```

Calls python 2.7.16

```
python3
```

Calls  python 3.5.2

I want to install a package that is available for both python 2 and python 3. When I do

```
conda install (package)
```

It installs for python 2, presumably becuase that's what "which python" is. However python 3 does not have access to it. How can I get conda to also install it for python 3?

Comment: I'm not so clearly understand but maybe you can check similiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda.

Comment: @byamba thanks but that's not really the same issue