# Conda will not update to 4.6.14 with 'conda update -n base -c defaults conda'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

When I use conda, it informs me that there's a newer version; however, when I try to update conda, it refuses to update anything beyond 4.5.11. I'm using Windows 10. I've raised an [issue on conda Github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8632), but unfrotunately no one has got back to me with a solution thus far. So I was hoping that someone here might have come across the issue and able to help out. One thing to note, the link contains relevant configuration details when I was on Windows 7, but I just upgraded to Windows 10 a few days ago. Anyway I tried the same conda command after the OS upgrade it hasn't changed anything. The issue still occurs.
Also, [this other issue I raised in conda Github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8633) regarding upgrading to the latest Python version in Anaconda, I'm guessing is also related to the same issue.

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.6.14

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.6.14

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right path on the GitHub site. Basically, you have to upgrade Python 3.5 first. There was an older answer that was helpful to me in doing this last year: [How to upgrade to Python 3.6 with Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711567/570918)

Comment: Thanks @merv. With the link you shared and having to create a new virtual environment for python 3.7, I managed to get it working. Many thanks