# upgrade python version in existing conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, upgrade, conda

I have a python3.5 (Ana)conda environment `myenv`. I installed many packages (and also my own custom packages) in that environment.
Can I update `myenv` to python3.6 without having to create a new environment and re-installing all the packages (manually)?
What would be the easiest way to migrate to python3.6?

Comment: Is this Anaconda environment your **base** env? If so, that is much more difficult and risky to do in-place. The safest transition is to export the env (`conda env export --no-builds`) and update the YAML to include Python 3.6. The local packages you'd have to handle manually. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda

Comment: The `--from-history` flag might also be useful in this context since it will generate a minimal env YAML that only includes explicitly requested files. However, I'm not sure if it captures `pip` installed packages.

Comment: @merv it's not my base env. Will try it ASAP (without the `--from-history` flag)

Comment: @merv strange, it seems that I already was at python3.6, however my IDE listed the environment as 3.5. I had probably upgraded it before. I didn't test your method, but since python is listed as a 'package' inside the YAML, I suspect your method will work, but what would probably *also* work (and be easier) is just updating the python 'package' inside the conda env.