# Update python on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

My current python version is :

[image]

---

When I search for available python using the code:

```
conda search python
```

Below is the output:

[image]

---

I want to update my python to the latest version.

I use the following commands:

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
conda config --show
```

It gives the following output, Please review it and let me know what is the issue.

```
add_anaconda_token: True

add_pip_as_python_dependency: True

aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl

allow_conda_downgrades: False

allow_cycles: True

allow_non_channel_urls: False

allow_softlinks: False

always_copy: False

always_softlink: False

always_yes: None

anaconda_upload: None

auto_activate_base: True

auto_stack: 0

auto_update_conda: True

bld_path: 

changeps1: True

channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org

channel_priority: flexible

channels:
  - defaults

client_ssl_cert: None

client_ssl_cert_key: None

clobber: False

conda_build: {}

create_default_packages: []

croot: /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld

custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com

custom_multichannels:
  defaults: 
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  local: 

debug: False

default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r

default_python: 3.7

default_threads: None

deps_modifier: not_set

dev: False

disallowed_packages: []

download_only: False

dry_run: False

enable_private_envs: False

env_prompt: ({default_env}) 

envs_dirs:
  - /opt/anaconda3/envs
  - /Users/aarav/.conda/envs

error_upload_url: https://conda.io/conda-post/unexpected-error

execute_threads: 1

extra_safety_checks: False

force: False

force_32bit: False

force_reinstall: False

force_remove: False

ignore_pinned: False

json: False

local_repodata_ttl: 1


migrated_channel_aliases: []

migrated_custom_channels: {}

non_admin_enabled: True

notify_outdated_conda: True

offline: False

override_channels_enabled: True

path_conflict: clobber

pinned_packages: []

pip_interop_enabled: False

pkgs_dirs:
  - /opt/anaconda3/pkgs
  - /Users/aarav/.conda/pkgs

proxy_servers: {}

quiet: False

remote_backoff_factor: 1

remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15

remote_max_retries: 3

remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0

repodata_fns:
  - current_repodata.json
  - repodata.json

repodata_threads: None

report_errors: None

restore_free_channel: False

rollback_enabled: True

root_prefix: /opt/anaconda3

safety_checks: warn

sat_solver: pycosat

separate_format_cache: False

shortcuts: True

show_channel_urls: None

solver_ignore_timestamps: False

ssl_verify: True

subdir: osx-64

subdirs:
  - osx-64
  - noarch

target_prefix_override: 

track_features: []

unsatisfiable_hints: True

unsatisfiable_hints_check_depth: 2

update_modifier: update_specs

use_index_cache: False

use_local: False

use_only_tar_bz2: False

verbosity: 0

verify_threads: 1

whitelist_channels: []
```

---

I also tried to run this :

```
conda install python=3.8.3 -d [--json]
```

I got this error:

[image]

I tried using install the latest version using the following command:

```
conda install python=3.8.3
```

It was This was the output:

[image]

The conda modules that have been installed are listed below :

```
conda list
```

---

```
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2020.02                  py37_0  
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
altgraph                  0.17                       py_0  
amqp                      2.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
applaunchservices         0.2.1                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astor                     0.8.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.4.1                    py37_0  
astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py37h01d97ff_1  
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.9.1                    py37_0  
billiard                  3.6.3.0                  pypi_0    pypi
bitarray                  1.2.2            py37haf1e3a3_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.4                      py_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     2.0.2                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37hf1fa96c_1  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
c-ares                    1.15.0            h1de35cc_1001  
ca-certificates           2020.4.5.2           hecda079_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
celery                    4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2020.4.5.2       py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.4.1                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.9.2            py37ha12b0ac_0  
cssselect                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
curl                      7.69.1               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.17          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.17.2                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.17.2                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.14              h517e14e_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diazo                     1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0  
distributed               2.17.0                   py37_0  
django                    1.7.11                   pypi_0    pypi
django-haystack           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
django-hitcounter         0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
django-revproxy           0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
django-taggit             1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.16                     py37_1  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
etiquetando               0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.8.2                      py_0  
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1  
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
google-auth               1.14.3                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
grpcio                    1.29.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h3134771_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html2text                 2020.1.16                pypi_0    pypi
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
hypothesis                5.11.0                     py_0  
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3  
idna                      2.9                        py_1  
imageio                   2.8.0                      py_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
imbalanced-learn          0.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        1.6.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        1.6.0                         0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0  
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
joblib                    0.15.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.6              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.1.4                      py_0  
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
keyring                   21.1.1                   py37_2  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37h04f5b5a_0  
kombu                     4.6.8                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.17.1               hddcf347_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.69.1               h051b688_0  
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h0a44026_6  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0  
liblief                   0.10.1               h0a44026_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libprotobuf               3.11.4               hd9629dc_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h0a44026_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha12b0ac_1  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvm-openmp               10.0.0               h28b9765_0  
llvmlite                  0.32.1           py37h8c7ce04_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.5.0            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h1de35cc_2  
macholib                  1.11                       py_0  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h9aa3819_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h959d312_0  
mock                      4.0.2                      py_0  
mongodb                   4.0.3                hccea1a4_0  
more-itertools            8.3.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  5.0.6                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0  
numba                     0.49.1           py37h86efe34_0  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37hce01a72_0  
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h7241aed_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37h3304bdc_1  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h0b31af3_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.3                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.3            py37h6c726b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.1.2            py37h4655f20_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_3  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
portaudio                 19.6.0               h647c56a_4  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0  
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37h0a44026_0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.10.1           py37haf313ee_0  
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyaudio                   0.2.11           py37h1de35cc_2  
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycryptodome              3.8.2            py37ha8bbb54_0  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37ha12b0ac_0  
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0  
pyinstaller               3.6              py37ha441bb4_5  
pylint                    2.5.2                    py37_0  
pymysql                   0.9.3                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
pysimplegui               4.18.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h5bccee9_0  
pytest                    5.4.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0  
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.7.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.7           hc70fcce_0_cpython  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0  
python-language-server    0.31.9                   py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0  
python.app                2                       py37_10  
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37h0a44026_0  
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.7.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.7.4                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  8.0                  h1de35cc_0  
redis                     3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
repoze-lru                0.7                      pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.23.0                   py37_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.17.0                     py_0  
rsa                       4.0                      pypi_0    pypi
rtree                     0.9.4                    py37_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h6c726b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9fa6033_0  
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                47.1.1                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.15.0                     py_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0  
sphinx                    3.0.4                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.1                      py_0  
spyder                    4.1.2                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            1.9.1                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.17           py37haf1e3a3_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               h5c1f38d_1  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py37haf1e3a3_0  
stemming                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0  
tbb                       2020.0               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
tensorboard               2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0.post3              pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.13.1                   py37_1    conda-forge/label/cf202003
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0           py37h24bf2e0_0    conda-forge/label/cf202003
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toml                      0.10.0           py37h28b3542_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h1de35cc_1  
tqdm                      4.46.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
typed-ast                 1.4.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.1                  py37_0  
ujson                     1.35             py37h1de35cc_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0  
vine                      1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
watchdog                  0.10.2           py37h0b31af3_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.9                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0  
whoosh                    2.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.9                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.19.4                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

But still, my python version is still 3.7.7

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to Python 3.6 with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda)

Comment: You probably have to create a new enviroment like `conda create -n py38 python=3.8` and make it your default environment, see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Answer (score 5):

This command usually will update to the latest version, but it seems this is not working for you.

```
conda update python
```

You can try this instead (Latest stable version is 3.8.3):

```
conda install python=3.8.3
```

However, you may want setup a new environment to be able to use multiple versions of python as upgrading may break your python scripts that run in 3.7.7. You can do this by using conda to create a new environment and then switch between the environments while you are testing and upgrading your scripts.

```
conda create --name test2 python=3.8.3
```

Also, the problem with the update command could be several. For example, if the channel list does not have a more recent version of python that is compatible with your environment, it won't update. To troubleshoot this we would need more information, such as

```
conda info
```

and

```
conda config --show
```

Think the problem is caused by mixing conda and pip installs in the same environment. This can be dangerous, as it will cause problems with some new installs or upgrades later on. conda won't know about pip details, and pip won't know about conda details. I suspect your Python upgrade has a dependency on one of the files installed through pip and gives up after a while.
Best practice is to use conda install if at all possible, and to create and use another environment. But if you still need a package that conda can't provide, then you can use pip. However, take note of the revision for that environment in case you have to roll back the pip install later.

To see the source of the install, look at the channel column. For example:

altgraph            0.17               py_0
amqp                2.5.2              pypi_0    pypi
imbalanced-learn    0.6.2              py_0      conda-forge

altgraph was installed using conda, amqp was installed using pip. The source for pip is the pypi website, that is why you see pypi in the last column (channel). Also, i can see you used the conda-forge channel for a few packages, such as imbalanced-learn. To change this environment in the future, you may need to add -c conda-forge

Comment: Thank You Donald for your help, I have updated the question. Please review it.

Comment: sorry, you don't type the "output" in the command. the command is: 'conda config --show`, can you post the output from this command?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: ok, the config looks normal. It is possible that you have an incompatable version of a package installed, or package clash. you may need to add the specific version switch to get this to update. can you test if it is possible to upgrade by running this command? `conda install python=3.8.3 -d [--json]` This won't actually update anything unless you remove the -d  switch. Also, if you include the --json switch you will get more details on the install/update process.

Comment: I have updated the question above with the screenshot of the [json] command.

Comment: oh, you need to remove the brackets before running the command. The brackets just show you that this text is optional. The command to run is `conda install python=3.8.3`. Also, can you run `conda list` and show me the output?

Comment: Done, Please review the post.

Comment: Ok, i can see you have used pip and conda in the same environment in the past. This can cause issues when upgrading, as conda won't know about pip details, and pip won't know about conda details. I suspect your Python upgrade has a dependency on one of the files installed through pip and gives up. Maybe the best solution is to go back to a previous base revision, possibly all the way back to the first revision to remove all the pip installs. You can find your changes to the base env using `conda list --revisions`, then select the one you want to use this way `conda install --revision 1`.

Comment: I did it but still I am getting the same conflict errors. I even ran " conda install -- revision 0 ", but same error of conflict is coming.

Comment: Since you have both pip installs and conda installs in your base env, and now you are not able to run basic commands using that env, i think your best option is to stop using the base env and create a new additional environment to use. This is the recommended usage for conda anyway. See this page for some details on how to setup and use conda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands. The other option is to reinstall conda completely, and use pip as little as possible.

Comment: Thank you Donald for helping me out. I wanted to know that how did you figure out that I had both pip and conda installs? Is it differentiable based on the channel column in the above screenshot?

Comment: altgraph                  0.17                py_0
amqp                      2.5.2               pypi_0    pypi
imbalanced-learn    0.6.2              py_0    conda-forge

To see the source of the install, look at the channel column. For example, altgraph was installed using conda, amqp was installed using pip. The source for pip is the pypi website, that is why you see pypi in the last column (channel). Also, i can see you used the conda-forge channel for a few packages, such as imbalanced-learn. To change this environment in the future, you may need to add -c conda-forge

Comment: Okay, Thank you.