# How to update Python to the latest version in Conda environment?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

I have tried the following command, but no luck there.

```
conda update python
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /home/shrivatsa/anaconda3/envs/machine_learning
  package name: python
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First check for all the python version available to install using `conda search python`. It will give list like below.

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                        2.7.13     hac47a24_15  pkgs/main           
.
.
.
python                         3.8.2      h191fe78_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.8.2      hcf32534_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.8.2     hcff3b4d_13  pkgs/main           
python                         3.8.2     hcff3b4d_14  pkgs/main           
python                         3.8.3      hcff3b4d_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.8.3      hcff3b4d_2  pkgs/main
```

Then, install the latest version using `conda install python=3.8.3`.