# upgrading python in Conda environment

Tags: python-3.x

I have python 2.7 installed on my Mac. I installed python 3.8.3 in an anaconda environment. However, when I type the command:

```
python --version
```

in the environment I still get python 2.7. how can I make my main python version 3.8.3 in this environment without completely getting rid of python 2.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update Python to the latest version in Conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726417/how-to-update-python-to-the-latest-version-in-conda-environment)

Comment: yes thanks for the link