# How can I update my Python version and keeping all the packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to ask you a question about the Python update.
If I wanted to update my Python version from the 3.10 to 3.11, what should I do?
And, most important, do I have to reinstall all the packages like Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib, ...?
In your opinion, when is needed to update it?

Comment: Are you using conda, virtualenv or plain python? Updating python version sometimes won't compatible be with the libraries.

Comment: No Conda, plain Python

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some security threat or some particularly new fun-ctionality, I wouldn't update too much between minor versions.

Then thanks to **pip** managing python packages is easy :

You can use pip freeze contextualized to a version, like :
`python3.10 -m pip freeze`

This will output a text with all libraries and their versions used by this specific binary.

You can put that into a file :
`python3.10 -m pip freeze > /tmp/python3.10.pip.txt`

And then install it with another version :
`python3.11 -m pip install -r /tmp/python3.10.pip.txt`

Comment: Note: Some specific versions of pandas won't work properly with python 3.11

Comment: Also might want to give a look to virtualenv, and docker maybe.

Comment: So, don't I need to download again python from the website? If my version is 3.10.2, do I have to write it or 3.10 is enough?

Comment: @FlavioBrienza it really depends on your OS and your aliases, when in command line, type in : python3 and then press <tab> twice, you'll get the python binaries in PATH.
But then yes, python3.10 should cover all that minor version and you don't have to go below in sub-versions.

Comment: So, can I do the entire process from the command line, just copying and pasting what you have written?

Comment: Depends on the OS and terminal, what are you running?

Comment: The pip freeze from a 3.10 env may be incorrect for a 3.11 env (example: [python-requires](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#requires-python) metadata and packages with [python_version](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers) environment markers). I would not recommend to recreate like this, instead install the "top-level" packages you want such as numpy, matplotlib, and then let pip on 3.11 solve the dependencies again.

Comment: Since 3.11 is relatively new, it's also quite possible/likely that some of the versions pinned in a 3.10 pip freeze _do not support Python 3.11 at all_, and will need to be updated to newer versions.

Comment: I'm running Windows 11. But my doubts are: do I have to go to the python website and installing a new version? Should I add the new version to the PATH? Should I delete the older version? Should I download all the packages like pandas, numpy, ... again? On internet there is nothing that clearly explains it

Comment: if you are on windows probably are you using the Anaconda distribution, whose engine behind the scenes is `conda`. In this case, try to follow the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix system (certainly Ubuntu, but I think also most of all the other Unix-bases OSs), you can have different python version installed.

#### Ubuntu

To install a python version, you can follow one of the many guides available in the internet, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/1658723). If you want additional information about the security of the procedure, you can read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398568/installing-python-who-is-deadsnakes-and-why-should-i-trust-them).

Then, you need to recreate an environment (virtualenv is strongly recommended!) . You can run:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/<python executable of the wanted version> <venv-name>
```

or:

```
<python of the wanted version> -m venv <venv-name>
```

for instance: `python3.11 -m venv myvenv`.

Then, you can activate the environment and install the dependencies. In general you can restore the packages through the `requirements.txt` file or equivalent `pyproject.toml` (depending on the package manager that you use). But when changing python version, and especially when upgrading it, it is recommended to reinstall manually the "top-level" packages, as @wim stated, because a different package version (if existing) is required to work with the new python version.

#### Other OSs

If you are on Windows or MacOS, probably you are using an Anaconda or conda-based python distribution. In either cases, you probably want to follow one of the methods explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536068/16797805).

After having upgraded python, you need to recreate the environment in an analogous way as it was explained for the Ubuntu case.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use Conda, I use plain Python. I am on Windows 11. Do I need to uninstall the older version and installing all the packages once again? Is it enough to use pip freeze to keep the packages on the new version?

Comment: I don't have much experience with plain python on Windows.. I guess that it is preferable to unistall the older version and install the newer one to avoid conflcts. Pip freeze ha the downsides already explained by @wim. Can't you take in consideration the usage of Anaconda, and in case yes, why? That should allow you to have multiple different python versions installed.